# PostgreSQL consuming large amount of memory for persistent connection

Tags: postgresql, memory, libpq

I have a C++ application which is making use of PostgreSQL 8.3 on Windows. We use the libpq interface.

We have a multi-threaded app where each thread opens a connection and keeps using without PQFinish it.

We notice that for each query (especially the SELECT statements) postgres.exe memory consumption would go up. It goes up as high as 1.3 GB. Eventually, postgres.exe crashes and forces our program to create a new connection.

Has anyone experienced this problem before?

EDIT: shared_buffer is currently set to be 128MB in our conf. file.

EDIT2: a workaround that we have in place right now is to call PQfinish for every transaction. But then, this slows down our processing a bit since establishing a connection every time is quite slow.

Answer (score 4):

In PostgreSQL, each connection has a dedicated backend. This backend not only holds connection and session state, but is also an execution engine. Backends aren't particularly cheap to leave lying around, and they cost both memory and synchronization overhead even when idle.

There's an optimum number of actively working backends for any given Pg server on any given workload, where adding more working backends slows things down rather than speeding it up. You want to find that point, and limit the number of backends to around that level. Unfortunately there's no magic recipe for this, it mostly involves benchmarking - on your hardware and with your workload.

If you need more connections than that, you should use a proxy or pooling system that allows you to separate "connection state" from "execution engine". Two popular choices are [PgBouncer](http://pgfoundry.org/projects/pgbouncer/) and [PgPool-II](http://www.pgpool.net/mediawiki/index.php/Main_Page) . You can maintain light-weight connections from your app to the proxy/pooler, and let it schedule the workload to keep the database server working at its optimum load. If too many queries come in, some wait before being executed instead of competing for resources and slowing down *all* queries on the server.

See the [postgresql wiki](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Replication,_Clustering,_and_Connection_Pooling).

Note that if your workload is read-mostly, and especially if it has items that don't change often for which you can determine a reliable [cache invalidation](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/TwoHardThings.html) scheme, you can also potentially use memcached or Redis to reduce your database workload. This requires application changes. PostgreSQL's `LISTEN` and `NOTIFY` will help you do sane cache invalidation.

Many database engines have some separation of execution engine and connection state built in to the core database engine's design. Sybase ASE certainly does, and I *think* Oracle does too, but I'm not too sure about the latter. Unfortunately, because of PostgreSQL's one-process-per-connection model it's not easy for it to pass work around between backends, making it harder for PostgreSQL to do this natively, so most people use a proxy or pool.

I strongly recommend that you read [PostgreSQL High Performance](http://www.packtpub.com/postgresql-90-high-performance/book). I don't have any relationship/affiliation with Greg Smith or the publisher<sup>*</sup>, I just think it's great and will be very useful if you're concerned about your DB's performance.

---

<sup>*</sup> ... well, I didn't when I wrote this. I work for the same company now.

Answer (score 1):

The memory usage is not necessarily a problem. PostgreSQL uses shared memory for some caching, and this memory does not count towards the size of the process memory usage until it's actually used. The more you use the process, the larger parts of the shared buffers will be active in it's address space.

If you have a large value for *shared_buffers*, this will happen. If you have it too large, the process can run out of address space and crash, yes.

Comment: we currently have it set to 128MB, and this doesnt prevent it from going up higher than 128 MB.

Comment: That certainly sounds worse. What are your settings for work_mem?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is probably that you don't close the transaction,
In PostgreSQL even if you do only selects without DML it runs in transaction which need to be rollback.
By adding rollback at the end of the transaction will reduce your memory problem